# Why my "new Question" button is not changing the question when i click the button?

Tags: reactjs

So the idea is when you click the button, you should see new question. But its not working and i don't know why :( Help!

```
  const Trivia = () => {
      const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState();
     
  
      React.useEffect(() => {

             fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1') 
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
             setQuestion(data.results[0].question);

             });
      }, [] )
      

      return(
      <div>
            <p>{question}</p> 
              
            <button onClick={() => }> New Question</button>
      </div>
      
      );
  };
      
  ReactDOM.render(<Trivia />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Comment: What you wanna do when you click the button? Open a popup with an input to set a new question? Or refetch a new question from API?

Comment: i just want that the new question comes when i click the button. No popup.    

 <p>{question}</p> 
                  
                <button onClick={() => setQuestion }> New Question</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to refetch a new question from your API when you click the button, I suggest you to export your API call into a function like that :

```
    const fetchQuestion = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setQuestion(data.results[0].question);
      });
  };
```

Then you can call it whenever you want, and your code should be like this :

```
const Trivia = () => {
  const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState();

  const fetchQuestion = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setQuestion(data.results[0].question);
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuestion();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{question}</p>

      <button onClick={fetchQuestion}>New Question</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Trivia />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```